# Preventing commas in decimal property for .NET Web API request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have a TestRequest class that includes a decimal property as follows:

```
public record TestRequest
{
    public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a POST endpoint in my .NET Web API controller that accepts an instance of `TestRequest`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(TestRequest request)
{
    // Some code here
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that users are able to send decimal values with commas, such as:

```
{
   "DecimalValue": "5,1"
}
```

Instead of throwing an error, my application is converting the value as if it were a string, resulting in the decimal value being set to 51.

I want to prevent users from sending decimal values with commas and instead throw an error indicating that the input format is invalid.

What would be the best approach to achieve this in my .NET Web API?

Comment: Sounds like you need to prevent that on the web page itself before it makes the request. The correct JSON would be `{"DecimalValue": 5.1 }` with no quotes and a `.`

Comment: @Charlieface I know how it would be the correct request, I just want to handle such "bad" requests as I pointed out in the question

Comment: I don't understand: are users writing their own JSON manually? Just do the correct thing from the webpage.

Comment: I don't mean the API is used from the webpage, let's assume that it is a public API and any kind of values are expected

Comment: Well if somebody sends you garbage what do they expect to get? They need to follow the spec. They could equally send you `51` in the first place, and still get wrong results. Do you want to prevent any use of quotes at all for decimals, which would in turn force the use of `.`? Which serializer are you using, `System.Text.Json` or Json.NET?

Comment: I use System.Text.Json by default and I want to return related response, that it is a wrong request in case of '5,1' and  I don't want it to be parsed as 51

Comment: It looks like their Culture is one that uses comma instead of period (most European countries).  Try detecting the culture from the request and set that culture when handling the request.  Look into request culture providers and localization middleware.

Comment: @hijinxbassist You are right, I want to set culture for my API, but I could not manage how to do it yet